What happens to proportional odds ordinal models around 6000 distinct observations?
Posted as a comment here about proportional odds ordinal models:

Unless you have more than about 6000 observations there are implementations that can work with the rank-ordering of all outcome values.

What happens to proportional odds ordinal models around distinct 6000 observations?

Following the links from the comment https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/ : " Note that the only efficient full likelihood software implementation at present (besides SAS JMP) for continuous $Y$ in large datasets is the orm function in the R rms package, which can efficiently handle more than 6000 intercepts (one less than the number of distinct values)."  It sounds like the limitation is not on the number of observations but on the number of unique response values/levels.  (Although I guess if you're using this to model continuous responses then (num obs == num unique response values ...)

@FrankHarrell Want to post that as an answer for a quick +25?

Minor note: In this post's title unique should be distinct.  Unique denotes a frequency of one, i.e, no ties.

Yes; nothing special happens at n=6000. You can use rms::orm for as many distinct  values as you want. Execution time is roughly linear in the number of distinct values. By the time you get to 6000, execution time is slow enough (say 90 seconds, for example) for some people to not want to wait. Interestingly you can use MASS:polr for large numbers of distinct values when you don't compute the Hessian. It's the Hessian that needs to make use of the sparse information matrix, as orm does.

Update: Version 7.0-0 of the R rms package will be released by mid January.  It allows for an unlimited number of intercepts (distinct Y values).  For n=300,000 with continuous Y and 299,999 intercepts with 20 covariates, the new orm function runs in 4 seconds on a single core.  More here.
